# CSS working in IE but not FF/Chrome

Tags: css

I feel like this is a very basic CSS question:

There seems to be a hidden "margin-top" in my CSS, which shows up in FF and Chrome, but not IE.  This is the page: [adambailin.com/projects](http://adambailin.com/projects/)

I want the project title to line up with the image.  Each project is in a #project div (thin white border-top).   The css for the image is

```
#project_image
{

 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 height: auto;
 padding: 2px;
 border: solid 1px #7E8AA2;
}
```

And the css for the description part is

```
#project_desc
{
 float: right;
 width:425px;
}
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You only use an ID on one single element in a HTML otherwise you will face all sorts of problems. It is possible that that's causing this issue as well. Use classes instead of IDs to style multiple elements.

Comment: (also check out http://doctype.com/ as it is a more suitable Q&A site for CSS problems than stackoverflow)

Comment: further to DrJ, make it <div class="project"> etc and .project{} in css. Class for things used mutliple times on a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an H4 tag which has it's own margin.

```
#project_desc h4 { margin-top:0 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right. All browsers add a margin to everything by default. IE default is 0. FF and others are in the 5 - 10 range. Zero the margin in your content divs and pretty much everything that you want it to be zero like p and h1. That will avoid this kind of thing every time.

Add `margin:0px` to both your id's here and it should work out.

Soapbox: People are always saying FF is always right; it's IE that's doing it wrong. Oh yeah, defaulting margins to something other then zero is doing it right? I think not. Frankly, both browsers have faults and both have merits.

Answer (score 1):

```
#project_desc h4
{
margin-top:0;
}
```

might help, try installing [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in firefox, its a web-devs best friend.

Answer (score 1):

just use this in css

```
h4 {margin-top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best plan... use a css reset stylesheet to solve this problem... every browser starts with different base styles.

[See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/is-it-ok-to-use-a-css-reset-stylesheet/167541#167541)